# How can I mount Christmas stocking hangers on a mantel that's not square?

Tags: granite, cover

I have a stone/granite fireplace with a stone mantel. The stone/granite mantel is uneven. It makes it hard to put my Christmas stocking hangers on it so that I can hang them. Is there something that I can put over the mantel so that the Christmas stocking holders will fit properly and securely without drilling or removing the mantel?

Comment: Picture of the mantle and the hangers will help.  Off hand maybe those temporary adhesive hooks that can be glued on and then peeled off.

Comment: This mostly suggests that the hangers you have are unsuitable to mantle you have, lacking any further detail at this time.

Comment: "The stone/granite mantel is uneven."  I think the word you are looking for is *rustic*.

Comment: "Uneven" - does that mean that it wasn't installed level so the hangers slide off, or does it have a rough surface on which the hangers don't get enough grip to prevent them from being pulled off by the weight of the stocking? As noted above, a picture would help a lot.

Comment: This qualifies as decorating advice in my book. It's a temporary thing for... decorations. VTC.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you could put a large wooden plank on top of the stone mantle.

So, if the mantle is say 10" wide, and your hangers need an inch to clamp to, you set a "2x12" plank on there (actual dimensions of 1-1/2 x 11-1/4 inches, typically - not even 11-1/2 inches these days on stuff that size, usually.)

```
||
||=========== Board to hang stockings from
||GGGGGGGG    Granite Mantel
||GGGGGGGG    Granite
||GGGGGGGG    Granite
BBBBB         Presumed brick, could be stone (fireplace)
BBBBB         Presumed brick, could be stone (fireplace)
BBBBB         Presumed brick, could be stone (fireplace)
BBBBB         Presumed brick, could be stone (fireplace)
-----         Top of fireplace opening
```

If your stockings are dreadfully heavy, set some weights on top of the board, back against the wall.

However, a different sort of hanger might be a simpler approach - something that just hooks on or sets in place rather than (presumably given the question, but you haven't shown your hooks) clamping in place.

```
||
||hhhhhhhhh
||GGGGGGGGh    
||GGGGGGGGh    
||GGGGGGGGh    
BBBBB     h    
BBBBB    h     
BBBBB   h      
BBBBB  h  h   A hook, which bends back under the edge
-----   hh     to make it hang in a stable manner.
```

Alternate version:

```
||   hhh
|| hh   hh
||hh      h
||GGGGGGGG h    
||GGGGGGGG h    
||GGGGGGGG h    
BBBBB     h    
BBBBB    h     
BBBBB   h      
BBBBB  h  h   A curvy hook, which bends back under the edge
-----   hh     to make it hang in a stable manner.
```